# How do I access javas ".class" attribute in jython code?

Tags: java, jython

In java, my code looks like:

```
new Injector(ClassToInjectOn.class, whatever)
```

so, the Injector class wants some `Class<>` argument. 
Works fine when doing things in Java.

But now I want to configure an injector object using jython.

I tried:

```
Injector(ClassToInjectOn.class, whatever)
```

results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: instance attr: class
```

I tried auto-completion; and found that I could use `ClassToInjectOn.__class__` ... but then the Class object that is passed into the injector will be java.lang.Class (but should be ClassToInjectOn.class).

Unfortunately searching for python and ".class" doesn't really provide useful answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In python `ClassToInjectOn` *is* the class object. This is why `ClassToInjectOn.__class__` gives you `java.lang.Class`, because that's what the class of a class object. So you need only write:

```
Injector(ClassToInjectOn, whatever)
```